# Optimum location of the most positive/negative spots of a battery pack

Tags: batteries

Which design would be better for the following batteries the most positive/negative connector? The reason i am asking is my original design is the one on the left, but someone told me the one on the right is better because the current is evenly distributed. Is that true?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1bBKd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: If you add the ESR of bus links and batteries the results will be different. You can model it in spice easily enough.

Comment: if there's continuity between them, what difference would it make to current?

Comment: The two schematics are identical. If you want comments about the layout, you should show a picture or drawing of the layout. Also, you should specify how much current will be flowing.

Comment: The second is better.  It puts the terminals more than a wrench-length apart.

Answer (score 0):

If the wire resistance is as poor as carbon piles, maybe. but a well built pack should make no difference.  There are bigger questions than this.

Answer (score 0):

They are the same on paper but in practice people swear the solution on the right will help the batteries last longer

Comment: Can you explain why?